# Why the function std::basic_streambuf::setg() takes non-const agruments

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I am checking the function `setg()` in the class `std::basic_streambuf`. It defined in the file streambuf.

The gcc version is 5.4.0

The compile option I am using is `-std=gnu++14`

```
void
setg(char_type* __gbeg, char_type* __gnext, char_type* __gend)
{
    _M_in_beg = __gbeg;
    _M_in_cur = __gnext;
    _M_in_end = __gend;
}
```

The member variables are declared as:

```
char_type*      _M_in_beg;     ///< Start of get area.
char_type*      _M_in_cur;     ///< Current read area.
char_type*      _M_in_end;     ///< End of get area.
char_type*      _M_out_beg;    ///< Start of put area.
char_type*      _M_out_cur;    ///< Current put area.
char_type*      _M_out_end;    ///< End of put area.
```

I understand that since the member variables are non-const `char_type*`, the function `setg()` can only take non-const arguments.
But the purpose of those pointers are retrieving things, those pointers `char_type *` should be declared as `const char_type*` in the first place, right?

Because the member variable pointers are non-const pointers, I would assume that the values those pointers pointed to can be changed in some specific circumstances.

My question is in what situations the `basic_streambuf` object will change values in the get area? If the get area content will not be changed, Is there a good reason that const pointers `cosnt char_type*` should not be used?

**Edit 1**
In that case, the member variables can be declared as:

```
char_type const *_M_in_beg;     ///< Start of get area.
char_type const *_M_in_cur;     ///< Current read area.
char_type const *_M_in_end;     ///< End of get area.
char_type       *_M_out_beg;    ///< Start of put area.
char_type       *_M_out_cur;    ///< Current put area.
char_type       *_M_out_end;    ///< End of put area.
```

So the `setg()` can be declared as:

```
void
setg(char_type const* __gbeg, char_type const* __gnext, char_type const* __gend)
```

A bit background story about the question. My colleague modified a function `foo()` which invokes `setg()` so the input parameter is non-const. but the input parameters of `foo()` should not be modified. Since the parameter `setg()` is non-const. The function parameters of `foo()` can NOT be const. The modification past his unit tests cases but failed mine due to the modification changed the input values. If the `setg()` takes const in the first place, the world is better.
**End of Edit 1**

PS While I read the function again the variable names impressed me, the second parameter of the function `setg()` named as `_gnext` and it is assigned to the pointer called `_M_in_cur`, I almost modified my code to increment the pointer to 1 before it passes into the function. Well done whoever named the parameter.

[basic_streambuf reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf)

Thank you in advance for any explanation you can provide

r0nG

Comment: You can argue that they can be declared as `char_type* const` but `char_type const*` won't work since it's not convertible to `char_type*`.

Comment: In a stream, the beginning and end of the get area do not correspond to the start and end of the stream, but of the local buffer.  In practice, most stream implementations use only one get buffer, so those boundaries do not change, but they may in stream implementations with more complex buffering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The get area is a buffer for reading characters from associated input sequence. If a read method is called but there are not enough characters in the get area, the `basic_streambuf` object will read the associated input sequence to update the contents in the get area. In this case, the contents in the get area are modified.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I updated my question to make is more clear. AFAIU, the get area is just 3 pointers pointing to an associated stream. So basically I believe the update get area operation is changing the pointers values to point to a new location.

Comment: @r0ng Anyway you should load characters from the associated input sequence to the place these pointers point to, and this operation is done probably through these pointers, so they cannot be defined as `const char_type*`. Of course, one can perform the load through other pointers or glvalues rather than these pointers, or just make them point directly to the associated input sequence, but the standard should not define the pointers as `const char_type*` to **force** the implementation to do so.  For your background, I don't think it is a good idea to use your arguments as these pointers.